# Post Loop - Wordpress - no title

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code as i'm trying to make an XML feed for Google shopping from my Wordpress shop:

```
query_posts('post_type=product&showposts=-1&&hide_empty=0');
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();


$columns.='<item>';

$columns.='<title>';
$columns.= $post–>post_title;
$columns.='</title>';

$columns.='<link>';
$columns.= 'http://mydomain.co.uk/products/'.$post–>post_name;
$columns.='</link>';

$columns.='<description>';
$columns.=$post–>post_content;
$columns.='</description>';

$columns.='<g:image_link>';
$columns.="http://www.example.com/".$result[$i]['image'];
$columns.='</g:image_link>';

$columns.='<g:price>';
$columns.=$result[$i]['Price'];
$columns.='</g:price>';

$columns.='<g:condition>';
$columns.='new';
$columns.='</g:condition>';

$columns.='<g:id>';
$columns.=$post->ID;;
$columns.='</g:id>';

$columns.='</item>';
endwhile; endif;
```

But for some reason I can't get the title, content or postname to work... but the ID will display ok!?

Any suggestions on where i'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Had copied the -> from the internet - seems to have been slightly different characters - retyped them and now it seems fine.  Thanks.

Comment: At least, vote for your own answer to mark the topic as answered.

Answer (score 0):

My WP is rusty, but what happens if you change

```
$columns.= $post–>post_title;
```

To

```
$columns.= the_title();
```

Comment: Seems to just display it rather than store in the variable for the xml output.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$columns.= $post–>post_title;
```

To

```
$columns.= get_the_title();
```

Codex: [get_the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)